# Find the sequences given their generating function.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Find the sequences given their generating function $$1)\ \ f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}
\\ 2)\ \ \  f(x)=\frac{1}{(x-2)^2}$$

How computing these two examples will be different from each other? They vary from the standard examples when the quadratic equation has 2 solutions. How to start with only basic equation $f(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2...$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint for (1) is the substitution $u=-x^2$.

The hint for (2) is to find the series for the function without the square and then differentiate function and series.